# Is there a way to use NSURLProtocol in a NSURLSession with custom config?

Tags: swift, nsurlsession, nsurlprotocol

I have a NSURLSession that runs in a background queue. I'm adding my `NSURLProtocol` subclass to the `NSURLsessionConfiguration.protocolClases` but the `override class func canInitWithRequest(request: NSURLRequest) -> Bool` never gets called.

This is how I'm adding my `NSURLProtocol`

```
let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
configuration.protocolClasses!.append(MockNetwork)
urlSession = NSURLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: operationQueue)
```

Also I tried with the session not running on background doing but also didn't work:

```
let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
configuration.protocolClasses!.append(MockNetwork)
urlSession = NSURLSession(configuration: configuration)
```

As this was not working I just tried:

```
urlSession = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
```

And calling this in my AppDelegate

```
NSURLProtocol.registerClass(MockNetwork)
```

This does work, what am I doing wrong?!

Comment: This does work, what am I doing wrong? Answer: Nothing :)

Comment: but I can't make it work when using a custom config in a background queue... this is driving me CRAZY

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After spending some more hours trying to find out why this wasn't working I found the way of doing it.

Instead of:

```
configuration.protocolClasses?.append(MockNetwork.self)
```

Do:

```
var protocolClasses = [AnyClass]()
protocolClasses.append(MockNetwork.self)

let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
configuration.protocolClasses = protocolClasses
```

After that change everything worked and not necessary to `URLProtocol.registerClass(MockNetwork.self)`

Comment: You would still have to register your custom protocol through NSURLProtocol.registerClass(MockNetwork) in case you were trying to intercept web view requests.

Comment: protocolClasses uses `AnyClass` not `AnyObject`. Your array would need to be `[AnyClass]()` instead.