# Swift - Log all requests in mac app

Tags: swift, swift2, nsurlprotocol

I have tried to use NSURLProtocol to log all requests in a Swift 2.3 project. However not all URL requests are being logged. Specifically all the Alamofire requests are not being recorded.

Sample code

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate{
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
        NSURLProtocol.registerClass(TestURLProtocol)
        Alamofire.request(.GET, SomeURL).responseSwiftyJSON({ (request, response, json, error) in })
    }
}

class TestURLProtocol: NSURLProtocol {
    override class func canInitWithRequest(request: NSURLRequest) -> Bool {
        print("request \(request.URL!)") // never called
        return false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because Alamofire uses the new `URLSession` API, which is not affected by the `NSURLProtocol.registerProtocol` call.

You have to create a `URLSession` with `URLSessionConfiguration` that has its `protocolClasses` array set to `[TestURLProtocol.self]`.

But with this you would have to use a custom `SessionManager` everywhere to log the requests, instead of using the implicit `Alamofire.request` I think.

Comment: I have tried to use the method from this response and it did not work. 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/28720198/1449607

Comment: Yeah, but you have to inject the configuration in the session manager and then use that instead of `Alamofire.request`

Comment: I am trying to also monitor third party services. I am looking for a solution that will let me monitor those requests without modifications of their code.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up using was the pod `OHHTTPStubs`. I added the following code to my app delegate to log every host being used.

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
    var hosts = [String: Int]()

    stub({ req in
        if let url = req.URL, let host = url.host{
            var count = 1
            if let c = hosts[host]{
                count = c + 1
            }
            hosts[host] = count

            print("Request #\(count): Host = \(host)")
        }
        return false
        },
         response:{_ in return OHHTTPStubsResponse()}
    );
}
```